# Playing encrypted video with libmedia have pauses in reproduction

Tags: android, video, encryption

I have a problem in my app playing a 20 minutes encrypted video with libmedia. At the beginning everything is fine: library works and play encrypted video... but after 6 minutes reproduction pauses during 20 seconds, after that video continue playing during 4 minutes and pauses again, restart 20 seconds later and pauses again... and so on.

Videos are playing on Android 4.1, 80MB size and use AES encryption. This is the code that we use at the end of the "onCreate" method:

```
private void startVideo() {

    mVideoView.requestFocus();
    mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {              
            finish();                    
        }           
    });

    try{
        SecretKeySpec skey = new SecretKeySpec("XXXXXxxxxxXXXXXX".getBytes(), "AES");     
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skey,new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));   

        Licensing.allow(this);
        mServer = new LocalSingleHttpServer();        

        mServer.setCipher(cipher);
        mServer.start();           

        String serverPath = mServer.getURL("myvideopath");      
        mVideoView.setVideoPath(serverPath);
        mVideoView.setMediaController(mMediaController);
        mVideoView.start();  

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mVideoView.setMediaController(null);
}
```

Seems like video is decrypted again on this pauses... but i don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")` It is not a streams cipher, is a block cipher.

Using `Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/NoPadding")` solve the problem.

Comment: does it have a good performance ? the library with this encryption algorithm ? It takes around 20 seconds for me before start playing the video (45MB)

Comment: Yes, the performance is very good. You don't need to wait. Try it!

Comment: I did. this performance issue happens with me. It takes around 20 seconds for me before start playing the video (45MB)

Comment: Hello esteban, I am also using the same library to play encrypted video. I am able to play videos of around 150MB without any issues. But if Video is more than 150MB it is not playing at all. I have posted a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34036072/android-playing-aes-encrypted-video-using-libeasy-library        .  Please help me

Comment: Sorry Prabhu, I've never try with videos bigger than 90MB, I don't know what the problem. Try to send an email to libeasy support, they helped me.

Comment: Thanks esteban. I sent email to libeasy support but they are not responding.  Now the actual issue is videos size I guess. Because some videos even with 500 mb are playing but some videos even with 45 mb are not playing.

Comment: So maybe the problem is the cipher method and not the size.

Comment: If possible can u share me the code u r using for encryption and the cipher method u r using